# masonry retrieve gutter value from css

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry, gutter

I'm using a responsive css grid and masonry. The css grid margins change with different  .wrapper sizes, so I was wondering if I can set a value for the gutter in the css file and retrieve the value in jquery

The masonry js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    var $container = $('.wrapper');
    //get the value from .gutter in css file
    var $gutter = parseInt($('.gutter').css('margin'), 10);

    $container.imagesLoaded( function(){
        $container.masonry({
            itemSelector : '.container',
            singleMode:true,
            isAnimated:true,
            gutterWidth: gutter
        });
    });
});
```

The css:

```
@media only screen and (min-width:1200px) {
.gutter {margin:20px}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 959px) {
.gutter {margin:10px}
}
```